# Angular schematics: apply rules to the current tree and then modify the tree

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I'm creating an Angular schematics.
I want to apply a rule to the current tree, and then modify the tree.

as explained in the following snippet, I want to apply the rule created, so `tree.exists("./file.txt")` returns `true`

```
export default function(options: any): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {
    let tmpl = apply(url("./files"), [template(options),move(".")]);
    let rule = chain([branchAndMerge(chain([mergeWith(tmpl)]))]);
     //how to apply this rule to the current tree, so it contains the files from ./files

    //assume ./files contain a file named myfile.txt
    console.log(tree.exists("./myfile.txt"))    


    tree.create("hello.txt", "");
    return tree;
  };
}
```

**notes**

`return rule;` creates /file.txt, but I want to create both files file.txt (through applying rules) and hello.txt by tree.create() function.

using tree.create() before applying rules, creates both files, but `tree.exists('./file.txt')` still returns false.

Comment: And the issue is?

Comment: read the comments inside the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Just call the `chain` without assigning a variable:

```js
export default function(options: any): Rule {
    return (tree: Tree) => {
        const templateSource = apply(
            url("./files"),
            [template(options), move(".")]
        );

        const rules: Rule[] = [];
        rules.push(mergeWith(templateSource, MergeStrategy.Overwrite));
        rules.push(createFiles());
        return chain(rules);
    };
}

function createFiles(): Rule {
    return (tree: Tree) => {
        // Check if ./files contain a file named myfile.txt
        if (tree.exists("./myfile.txt")) {
            // Do whatever you want.
        }

        // You should check if it exists. If it does, use ovewrite instead.
        tree.create("hello.txt", "");
        return tree;
    }
}
```

And always try to provide some merge strategy.

Comment: didn't work, although returning the rule creating the file 

i.e: return chain(...), but this method doesn't give the chance to complete the code after returning.

also ` chain([branchAndMerge(chain([mergeWith(tmpl)]))]);` didn't work.

Comment: Maybe split the if-create part in another function, return the rule and chaining with the previous one could work.

Comment: did you test it yourself? if you did, please give me the tested code.

Comment: Check the edited answer. I didn't test it but that's what I do on most of my schematics.